# How to use offset in navbar-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie in bootstrap. I have code:

```
<header class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header"> <a href="." class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">-->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="nav"><a href=".">Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav"><a href=".">Item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li  class="nav"><a href=".">Item 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</header>
```

So i want use navbar-right, but i would like use also offset (2) from right.

Now is:

```
BRAND x x x x x x x x Item1 Item2 Item3
```

i would like receive:

```
BRAND x x x x x x Item1 Item2 Item3 x x
```

ONLINE demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7LcLE/

Comment: you could use `margin-right` property of css to specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
<div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right:10%;">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  </div>
 </nav> 

 <div class="container">
           <h3>Right Aligned Navbar</h3>
          <p>The .navbar-right class is used to right-align navigation bar buttons.</p>
    </div>

</body>
```